# How to Perform RR-Net MK3 Detection on VICE Commodore 64 Emulator?

Tags: commodore-64, emulation, network

RR-Net documentation describes a [detection algorithm](http://wiki.icomp.de/wiki/RR-Net#Detecting_MK3) for the MK3 model. The algorithm is supposed to reveal the last four hex digits of the MAC address. According to documentation the MAC address `28:CD:4C:FF:<HI>:<LO>` should have the value `<HI>` stored at `$de0c`. The default MAC is supposed to be `28:CD:4C:FF:FB:FF`. I would thus expect `PRINT(PEEK(56844))` to return `251` to match the `FB` of the default. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does it return? Is it consistent between runs? Across power cycles?